# Know a personal name’s pronunciation but not its spelling

Tags: word-choice

Suppose I heard three local residents talking about the bridge construction on a radio or podcast show.

- **C**ara Deleon: I don’t know if it is **K**ara.
- M**u**ha**mma**d Alif: I don’t know if it is M**o**ha**mma**d, M**o**ha**mme**d, M**o**ha**ma**d, M**o**ha**me**d, etc.
- H**oà**ng **T**ấn Nguyễn: If I only speak English but not Vietnamese, I would guess that the spelling of the name is H**oo**ang **D**an.

I only know the pronunciation of the name, not the spelling. Suppose I have no way to get the spelling of their names. When I write an article, how do I let readers know that these spellings are inferred from pronunciation, and may not be the correct spelling?

H**oo**ang **D**an Nguyen (_____________), said ...

Comment: Should you be writing an article where you are unable to contact your sources and verify the facts? Without documentation, it's unsubstantiated hearsay. Contact the producers of the show. If they won't give you the names, they'll likely tell you why they won't.

Comment: I don't think that the source verification has relation to this. For example, assume I get an Arabic-speaking podcast and Arabic-written news report from Egypt, which mentioned a person named محمد عليف (Muhammad Alif). The producer of the show only knows the Arabic spelling of عليف (Muhammad), not in the Latin alphabet. Even worst, if Muhammad does not have a passport himself or does not understand languages written in Latin letters such as English, he may not know how to write his name in Latin letters.

Comment: So, I want readers to know that the Muhammad is just recorded by sound, not necessarily the actual spelling. Note عليف can be Mohammad, Mohammed, Mohamad, Mohamed, etc in Latin alphabet, depending on how the authority recorded in passport.

Comment: If you're converting Arabic to English, there are various style guides for this, and you should choose one (or follow the one you are told to use) and stick to it. This is a separate issue to names you hear but can't spell. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [style guide for Transcribe.com](http://support.onespace.com/training-resources/transcription-style-guide) recommends putting "[phonetic]" next to names the transcriber doesn't know how to spell. I think that would work here too (paralleling "[sic]").

You may be able to get a better spelling, however:

- Get help from someone familiar with the name's language of origin if it's not your own. A native (or even semi-proficient) speaker of English would never guess something like "Tany" when the name sounded like "Danny" (though they couldn't know if it was spelled with an I or Y).
- Some names won't have only one correct transliterated spelling if they are written in a different script than what you're writing in. [Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese), for example, has three systems of romanization. In a case like this, where the person doesn't already have a transliteration they're using, I would just pick the most popular transliteration.
- If it's a full name, Google your best guesses for it and see if you can find their online presence. If you're searching effectively (e.g. using quotes), then this isn't as long a shot as it sounds.

Answer (score -2):

One way of conveying the sound of a word in print is to use the [International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).

It is an internationally recognised system which matches a character to a sound.
The characters are conventionally set between two forward slashes: / /.

Where in Standard English, we use a single letter 'a' for a number of sounds, the IPA gives the option of mapping each specific sound. For example:

the letter 'a' as used to indicate a long vowel: b*a*lm br*a* - IPA: /ɑː/

the letter 'a' as used to indicate a short vowel: *a*t p*a*t - IPA: /æ/

the letter 'a' as used to indicate a dipthong: f*a*ce - IPA: /eɪ/

Where two consonants are used as a consonant cluster to indicate a single sound, the IPA provides a single character. For example:

a consonant cluster made up of two consonants (s,h) stands for one sound (sh), as in *sh*ip *sh*in - IPA: /ʃ/

IPA notation allows for sounds used in other languages such as glottal stops, or the ʿayn (ع) in Arabic, which, in the IPA, appears as /ʕ/.

There are conventions for transliterating Arabic sounds into Cyrillic script, foremost amongst these being the IJMES, and the Library of Congress approaches (cited [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/international-journal-of-middle-east-studies/information/author-resources/ijmes-translation-and-transliteration-guide)). Others are listed on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic#Comparison_table).

Comment: I don’t think your solution satisfy my need. Sometimes even I don’t know which language the name come from. I just want reder know that I hear the name but I’m not sure about the spelling.

Comment: I don't see where the problem is. If you know the sounds and the IPA, you don't need to know which language the word is associated with. You just need to know the IPA character that matches the sound.